# Replacing a symbolic fraction in a matrix by pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

I have the following 4x4 symbolic matrix

```
{{-((x y (-1 + z))/(2 (-x + y))), (y (-Sqrt[z] + z))/(2 (-x + y)), (
  y (-1 + Sqrt[z]))/(2 (-x + y)), (d x y (-1 + Sqrt[z]))/(
  2 (-x + y))}, {(y (-Sqrt[z] + z))/(2 (-x + y)), 
  v/(-1 + u^2) - w + (2 Sqrt[z] - z)/(-2 x + 2 y), -(Sqrt[
   z]/(-2 x + 2 y)), 1/2 (w + (d x Sqrt[z])/(x - y))}, {(
  y (-1 + Sqrt[z]))/(2 (-x + y)), -(Sqrt[z]/(-2 x + 2 y)), 
  1/(-2 x + 2 y), (d y)/(-2 x + 2 y)}, {(d x y (-1 + Sqrt[z]))/(
  2 (-x + y)), 1/2 (w + (d x Sqrt[z])/(x - y)), (d y)/(-2 x + 2 y), 
  v + (d^2 x y)/(-2 x + 2 y)}}
```

An image of the matrix is as follows:
[image]

I want to replace all the terms of the form `xy/(x-y)` with `p`, e.g., the (1,1)-th element should become `(-1+z) p /2`, (1,2)-th element should become `(p (Sqrt[z] - z))/(2 x)` and so on. Is there a way to do this systematically in Mathematica? Any tips or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: try `expr /. x y -> p (x - y) // Simplify`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that does not work, e.g., the (2,2)-th element `(y (-Sqrt[z] + z))/(2 (-x + y))` remains the same.

Comment: @TDH you need to add as many changes as needed, klglr showed one example. You can do  `mat/. x y->p (x-y)/.y/(y-x)->-p/x` for example to change the second one. If there more patterns are overlooked, just add more as needed.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbhGL.png)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nasser, I will try that. The original matrix is actually much larger and has many terms of similar patterns, so I was wondering if there is one pattern to search and replace.

Comment: The standard way would be to do simplify with side relation, as in `rel=x*y/(x-y)==Unevaluated[p]; Simplify[-((x y (-1+z))/(2 (-x+y))),{rel}]` ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPeNI.png)  but this also does not work for all entries in your matrix. Simplification with side relation is not very robust in Mathematica.

Comment: I see, okay. Let me keep the question open for now, in case someone has a compact solution to this particular problem. Thanks again @Nasser!

Comment: how about `expr /. y -> (p x)/(p + x) // Simplify`?

Comment: I take it that you want to introduce p in every element, even if it does not contain x y/(x-y). This can be done by: `Map[(# p  (x - y)/(x y)) &, t, {2}] // Simplify`

Comment: @DanielHuber nice approach. It gives different result from what kglr suggested above, so it is up to the OP to decide which they want. Here is the difference  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VObpR.png)  but I like your method. It seems it eliminates all the guess work on what pattern to use.

Comment: @DanielHuber, this is great, yes this was what I wanted, and this works great for my purpose. Thanks very much! Thanks also to kglr and Nasser for the great discussion, really appreciate your help and insight!